# mariadb 10.1: Access denied for user, from ipv6 only

Tags: ipv6, mariadb

Adding an access record with host `%`, or with host `smtp.acme.com` does not provide access when accessing via IPv6. Nor does using the specific IPv6 address. I only get 'access denied'.

The SQL server is listening on Ipv6 (:::3306).

The User table has these records;

```
User   Host
smtp   %
```

Or, alternatively, these;

```
User   Host
smtp   <ipv4 of sql.acme.com>    
smtp   <ipv6 of sql.acme.com>
smtp   127.0.0.1
smtp   localhost
```

These connections are tried:

```
# Run from the server smtp.acme.com to sql.acme.com: 

mysql -usmtp -h sql.acme.com -D mydb -p<password>  ## Fails, access denied
mysql -usmtp -h <ipv4 of sql.acme.com> -D mydb -p<password> ## works
mysql -usmtp -h <ipv6 of sql.acme.com> -D mydb -p<password> ## Fails, access denied

# Run locally: 

mysql -usmtp -p<password>  ## works. 
mysql -usmtp -h localhost -p<password> ## works. 
mysql -usmtp -h 127.0.0.1 -p<password> ## works.
```

In other words, failure seems to occur only if communicating via IPv6. Even if these records do exist.

The password must be correct, as the version using '%' does function.

How?

Comment: Is that "Host: ipvx of sql.acme.com" a typo for smtp.acme.com, or is it really specifying the sql server's address?

Comment: It's hard-coding the address. This seems to work, well, for ipv4 for now.

Comment: I mean, the address of which machine? And are you sure the real connections are being made from that address? Does it match the address that's being shown in MariaDB server logs, in its "authentication failed" notices?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem.

Step 1: Don't use PHPmyadmin for this. Or, if you do, directly manipulate the `user` and `db` tables and don't use the UI for making/changing users: it's buggy.

In addition to this: The two tables where permissions are defined: `mysql.db & mysql.user` are not independent in the way you might think. Instead, the `user` table is used to select which host is connecting, then the `db` table is checked for permissions to the database it's connecting to for an *exact match*. If `user` contains `2007.1.2.3::23` but `db` only contains a rule for `%`, logging in over an IPv6 connection will still result in `access denied`, even though this doesn't appear to make sense.

The solution is to explicitly have access records for `2007.1.2.3::23`, in both the `mysql.db` and `mysql.user` tables.